# How do I automatically inject HTML code into a Shopify .liquid file?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I want to have a Shopify app that allows me to automatically (so that the user doesn't have to edit the code) add code into one of a user's .liquid files. I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Comment: Refer to the asset API: https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/online_store/asset

Comment: You should stick to using Script Tags. You can modify the DOM for your App, and when the user uninstalls your App, your code nicely disappears too. Otherwise, if you edit their theme automatically, that is, if you edit Liquid files with code, your code changes will become a nuisance over time.